# Critical values - function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that the critical values of the curve

$f(x) = -2x^3 + kx^2 + 6 $ are $0$ and $3$ , show that $k=9$

I started off by finding the derivatives of the function -

$f'(x) = -6x^2 + 2kx $

I set $f'(x) = 0 $ to find the $x$ values of the critical points .

$-6x^2 + 2kx = 0 $

$ -2(3x-k)= 0 $

$x = 0 , x= \frac{k}{3} $

The critical value $'0'$ obviously belong to the $x=0 $

But it is the $x=  \frac{k}{3}$ where I got stuck .

$-2( \frac{k}{3})^3 + k( \frac{k}{3})^2 +6 = 0$

$-3 =\frac{-2k^3+3k^3}{27} $

$k^3 = -81 $

I can't seem to show that k = 9 . Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You are told that the critical values of $f(x)$ are $0$ and $3$. You solved $f'(x) = 0$ which gave you that the critical values are $0$ and $\frac{k}{3}$. Now, you have found a critical value that you were given ($x = 0$), and you have discovered one that you were not given ($x = \frac{k}{3}$).

This means that $\frac{k}{3} = 3$. Therefore, $k = 9$.

Comment: Aren't the 0 And 3 suppose to be the "so called" y values of the critical point ?

Comment: No. $0$ and $3$ are the $x$ values. The $y$ values at the first derivative are in each case $0$. You would need to compute the $y$ values for the original equation by substituting $0$ and $3$ for $x$.

Comment: (+1) Good answer, but a little more explanation about where the $3$ on the LHS came from would be better, I think.